# Compute the derivative of a function

Tags: c#, mathematics

> *1.11 Arranging the derivative of a function
>
>   The derivative of any function f (x) at x0 can be estimated according to the following formula:*
>
> [image]
>
> *Write a program that prints three columns of numbers: x, f (x) and the derivative f '(x) for some simple functions, e.g. sin (x) or arctan(x).*

```
public static class Derrivative
{
    public static double Compute(Func<double, double> f, double x0, double h)
    {
        return (f(x0+h) - f(x0-h)) / (2*h);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = 10;

        Console.WriteLine("Derivative of sin(x)");

        Func<double, double> function = Math.Sin;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t{function(i)}\t{Derrivative.Compute(function, i, 0.5)}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Derivative of arctan(x)");

        function = Math.Atan;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t{function(i)}\t{Derrivative.Compute(function, i, 0.5)}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Kindly, review this source code.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the for loop to a function `printFunction(f, N)`

Since you are using a known formula I suggest you use the names in the formula. Meaning i->x
function->f.